# Bind to open port in specific range

Tags: python, sockets, networking, port

I want to bind a socket to listen on any open port within a certain range.  Typically I bind to zero and the operating system is good about giving me a random open port.  However now I need to stay within a certain range like `4000-5000` specified by a firewall.  How do I ask the OS for an open port within this range?

I'm doing this from Python.  I am interested in a cross-platform solution but would settle for something Linux-specific.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a function to do that. Something like this.

It just picks a port by random within the range given and tries to bind to it. If it has already been taken, a socket error 98 is raised. Then loop and choose another until successful, or exit if still unsuccessful after 10 attempts to prevent a deadlock.  The main program calls this function and listens to the socket. Getsockname can be used to display the port if needed.

```
import socket
import random

def bind_to_random_socket(low, up):
    _counter = 0
    foo = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    while True:
        try:
            _port = random.randint(low, up)
            foo.bind(("localhost", _port))
            return foo
        except:
            counter += 1

        if counter > 10:
            print "cannot find a free port within range"
            exit(1)


_ns = bind_to_random_socket(4000, 4200)
# to get the port number:
_addr, _port = _ns.getsockname()
print _port

_ns.listen(1)
```

Hope this helps.

Hannu

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small piece of code once to for exactly the same purpose

```
# SWAMI KARUPPASWAMI THUNNAI
import socket

class Ports:
    """
    This class is ued to find all the open ports present
    """
    __upper_bound = 0
    __lower_bound = 0
    __ip = "127.0.0.1" # change your i.p if it is not your machine IP
    __ports = [] # our actively available ports
    # used to set upper and lower bounds i.e the range of the ports to be scanned
    def __init__(self,initial,final):
        self.__lower_bound=initial
        self.__upper_bound=final

    # a method which scans for the range of ports
    def scan_for_ports(self):
        for i in range(self.__lower_bound,self.__upper_bound):
            print("[SCANNING]: "+str(i))
            check = self.is_port_opened(i)
            if check == 0:
                self.__ports.append(i) # append our opened port no
    # a method to find whether a port is opened
    def is_port_opened(self,portNo):
        try:
            client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            connection = client.connect_ex((self.__ip,portNo)) # remember it is a tuple
            port_opened = connection
            client.close()
            print(port_opened)
            return port_opened
        except socket.error as e:
            print("SOCKET CANNOT BE CREATED! Do you have admin previlidges? or the port may be closed!")
            print(e)
            return -1
        return -1
    # A method to get the list of open ports
    def get_list(self):
        for i in self.__ports:
            print("OPENED: "+str(i))


if __name__=="__main__":
    ports = Ports(75,81)
    ports.scan_for_ports()
    ports.get_list()
```

Now, you can easily write a client to listen on the specific port. I have opened a port (80) on my computer using a small python script for few minutes to test and the result was fine see here!

[image]

Comment: I think, this is the proper, exception handled, object oriented solution and cross-platformed solution which you are looking for.